# Nested fields - RoR - link_to_add_associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using cocoon and nested fields in a form with 3 tables as shown in this db scheme :)
[image]
I want to add a new menu so in a menus/new.html.erb I have :

```
    <%= simple_form_for @menu do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "name", label_method: :name, value_method: :id, include_blank: true %>

  <h3>Portions</h3>
  <div id='portions'>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :portions do |portion| %>
      <%= render 'portion_fields', :f => portion %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add portion', f, :portions %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'valider' %>
<% end %>
```

in my partial for the nested fields _portion_fields.html.erb :

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
    <%= f.association :aliment, label: "Intitulé de l'aliment", label_method: :label, value_method: :id, include_blank: true %>
    <%= f.input :portion_qty, label: "Qté", placeholder:"portions", as: :integer %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove portion", f %>
</div>
```

and my models :

```
  class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :portions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :aliments, through: :portions, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :portions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end



 class Aliment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :portions
  has_many :menus, through: :portions, dependent: :destroy
end

    class Portion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :aliment, foreign_key: :aliment_id
  belongs_to :menu, foreign_key: :menu_id
end
```

the error is telling me that :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_remove_association` helper (`Cocoon::ViewHelpers`) gets loaded on app start from cocoon railtie, this error may happen if you did not restart your app server after gem installation (also do a `spring stop` to be sure).